# Filter data from database by passing multiple nullable values

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database

I have a table with n numbers of column, and i want to filter data by n numbers of nullable parameters,
instead of writing n times if else condition is there any way to resolve this problem either in c# (Linq,Entity framework) or in SQL with queries.
if any one have any solution please give the solution with an example.
Thanking you.

Comment: Are you looking to have code search for null values, or are you looking to have code that allows 2 or 5 or 10 parameters that are all optional?  In other words, you want to have as many optional parameters as you want?

Comment: yes i am looking one simple solution for multiple parameters that are all optional.

Comment: Ok - see below as how one can go about this

Answer (score 1):

sure, you can have optional parameters in that sql.

The way you do this? You don't include the parameters in the sql, and then ONLY add the parameters as you need them! That way, you don't need all those extra conditions in the sql that is the condition, and then also the test for the @Param = null.

So, lets assume that I can search for City, or City + HotelName. And lets toss in a [x] Only search for Active Hotels. Or we search just for Hotelname. Or all 3 values!

As you WELL note, this becomes a harry ball of parameters that has to deal with only 3 choices (6 possible permutations). I can only imagine how bad this gets if you have 5 or 6 possible and optional value.

so, the simple solution? Well, we split the sql into a the base query, and then add the parameters on the fly. We STILL want (and get) strong type parameter checking, and thus get sql injection protection which of course is a important goal here.

We thus have this setup:

[image]

And the search then does this:

```
public void loadgrid()
{
string strSQL;
string strWhere;
strSQL = "select ID, FirstName, LastName, HotelName, City, Province from tblHotels";
strWhere = "";

using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, new SqlConnection(My.Settings.Test3)))
{
    if (txtHotelName.Text != "")
    {
        // search for hotel name
        strWhere = "(HotelName = @HotelName)";
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@HotelName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtHotelName.Text;
    }

    if (txtCity.Text != "")
    {
        if (strWhere != "")
            strWhere += " AND ";
        strWhere += "(City = @City)";
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCity.Text;
    }

    if (chkOnlyActive.Checked == true)
    {
        if (strWhere != "")
            strWhere += " AND ";
        strWhere += strWhere + "(HotelActive = @Active)";
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Active", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 1;
    }

    if (strWhere != "")
        cmdSQL.CommandText = strSQL + " WHERE " + strWhere;

    cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
    DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
    rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader);

    ListView1.DataSource = rstData;
    ListView1.DataBind();
}
}
```

So note how we simply build up the where clause. And you note that there is NOTHING that prevents us from changing the sql command text - and we are also 100% able to add parameters on the fly (adding them does not force a check against the sql - only at execute time.

As a result? We can add 5 more criteria. They are optional, they don't require us to make a huge long sql query with a gazillion parameters that we may will not want to use or even need.

And as above shows, we there are NEVER sting concatenation of the user inputs - they ALWAYS are used ONLY with parameter values.

So, for any text box, check box, combo box or whatever? We simply ignore them when they are not filled out. They are thus all optional, and quite much ignored in our code. The above setup thus would allow us with easy to add 2 or 5 more optional parameters.

Note in above, we always "check" if the where clause already has some value - and if so, then we add the " AND " clause in front. We could I suppose use " OR " here, but it depends on the kind of search you want.

Answer (score 1):

I nice 'trick' that can be used in both SQL statements and LINQ queries is to allow nulls on your query params and then check for a matching value or null on each parameter.

We make our params nullable and check each against their respective field/property or for null.

Basically, we tell the query to give us all records where the input parameter matches the property value **OR** if the input parameter is null we short circuit that param essentially causing our query to ignore that param. This effectively gives a parameter that is treated as optional when it's null and not optional otherwise.

Using this method you can easily add more optional parameters.

```
IList<ThingToQuery> things = new List<ThingToQuery>();
things.Add(new ThingToQuery(){ Property1 = "Thing1", Property2 = 100, Property3 = new DateTime(2001,1,1)});
things.Add(new ThingToQuery() { Property1 = "Thing2", Property2 = 100, Property3 = new DateTime(2002, 2, 2) });
things.Add(new ThingToQuery() { Property1 = "Thing3", Property2 = 300, Property3 = new DateTime(2003, 3, 3) });

// query sample #1 - prepare params
string queryParam1 = "Thing1";
int? queryParam2 = 100;
DateTime? queryParam3 = null;

// in our query we check for a matching value or if the param is null
List<ThingToQuery> results = things.Where(t => (t.Property1 == queryParam1 || queryParam1 == null)
                                          && (t.Property2 == queryParam2 || queryParam2 == null)
                                          && (t.Property3 == queryParam3 || queryParam3 == null)
            ).ToList();

// query sample #1 results
// Thing1, 100, 1/1/2001 12:00:00 AM

// query sample #2 - prepare params
string queryParam1 = null;
int? queryParam2 = 100;
DateTime? queryParam3 = null;

// query sample #2 results
// Thing1, 100, 1/1/2001 12:00:00 AM
// Thing2, 100, 2/2/2002 12:00:00 AM
```

A simple SQL example...

```
SELECT * FROM Users u
    WHERE (u.UserName = @UserName OR @UserName IS NULL)
    OR (u.FavoriteColor = @FavColor OR @FavColor IS NULL)
```

Comment: You do avoid string concatenation, but for each new parameter we only have to go in code and add that ONE if/then code block. For each parameter you have, you have to go and modify the original sql query text - two places in code. and for each parameter, you have to include the condition AND ALSO the @Parm  = null test. So you editing two places, and you have double condition for each parameter. So, there are trade offs with each approach. With 20 parameters you have 40 conditions, and in most cases most of them are not being used. So, there are tradeoffs - no one solution is the only answer.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal "no one solution is the only answer.", correct and that's why I posted my answer. It's not perfect and it can be improved, the fact remains I've used this method with success. So, with it's 'imperfections' and all, it's still a valid option.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I think I see why you made your comment. I didn't mean to imply my answer was better when I mentioned the 'dynamic WHERE clause building'. I've removed that line from my answer.

Comment: No worries  - everyone should feel 100% to make their case. I mean you jumping in, spending time, offering code, and helping. I would not worry. I mean, really, that idea and code is still great. Any offerings of help on SO? Man, that's just gold and valuable time and knowledge your offering here - we can't discourage that on SO. As always, everyone (including me) tends to think that our way is the best way - there is 100's of ways to skin this cat - your points, your ideas, and your contributions stand on their own. No worries - none at all!